# Will an INSTEAD OF trigger always fire before an AFTER trigger on the same table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

If I have an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger and an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the same table in SQL Server, is the execution order of those guaranteed to be INSTEAD OF first and then AFTER?

If so, will the inserted table in the AFTER trigger always see the result of the INSTEAD OF trigger?

My specific use case is that the INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger is updating what is the functional equivalent of a computed column and the AFTER UPDATE trigger has logic that is using that computed column.

Comment: Have you put both triggers on a table and tried it? What was the outcome?

Comment: If your instead of trigger is functioning like a computed column why do you need a trigger? Can you use a computed column? Since you are concerned about the order of triggers you should take a look at this article. It explains how you can manage and when instead of triggers fire. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189568.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange: Computed columns cause some performance issues for us, even with PERSISTED. That choice is out of scope for the question.

Comment: I don't see how an instead of trigger is going to perform better but that is your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Books online:

> AFTER triggers fire after the triggering action (INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE), INSTEAD OF triggers and constraints are processed.

Comment: Thanks, my Google-fu failed me. For anyone else, here's the link to the source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175943%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I don't understand anything from the quotation as to being before or after. In lieu, you would say `INSTEAD OF triggers fire in place of the triggering action and before constraints are processed.`